# Why do Many People Tend to Think That Natural Things are Better than Artificial?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias

It is common for some people to think that natural things and products are better while many artificial products are seen as bad. Why are many people subjects to this fallacy? What in our psychology can explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This question will likely solicit opinion-based answers, which will get it closed.  The reason is probably a cultural one, but how do you propose to investigate it?  Adding details of what sort of evidence you are looking for would help.

Comment: If there are research on the phenomenon I would like to hear about them.

Comment: The common name for this, [_appeal to nature fallacy_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_nature), should get you started finding some resources based on which you perhaps can formulate a more specific question. In fact, simply including a reference to this term in your question would greatly improve it. It provides evidence there is a reason for asking this question.

Comment: You mean like some research on the topic?